# C Function is deprecated

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, readline

I used the code in below link:

[Readline Library](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html)

And I defined a struct like this

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;           /* User printable name of the function. */
  Function *func;       /* Function to call to do the job. */
  char *doc;            /* Documentation for this function.  */
} COMMAND;
```

When I compile the code the compiler displays these warnings:

**"Function is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]"**

So what type should I change if I cannot use the function type?

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What is the *entire exact error that you get*?

Comment: Look at the warning message, it will also tell you which function is deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Function` is a `typedef` (an alias of a pointer to function returning `int`) marked as deprecated by the [library](https://fossies.org/diffs/readline/6.3_vs_7.0/rltypedefs.h-diff.html):

```
typedef int Function () __attribute__ ((deprecated));
```

Just use:

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;            /* User printable name of the function. */
  int (*func)();         /* Function to call to do the job. */
  char *doc;             /* Documentation for this function.  */
} COMMAND;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should deprecate Function. And the following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*Function)();

typedef struct {
    char *name;           /* User printable name of the function. */
    Function *func;       /* Function to call to do the job. */
    char *doc;            /* Documentation for this function.  */
}COMMAND;

int main() {
    COMMAND commond;

    puts( "end" );



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not my down-vote, but…  The trouble with this suggestion is that the code uses (and needs to use) a header that includes the `typedef` for `Function`, but it is annotated as 'deprecated' (which means do not use).  Your code won't work properly if the other header has been included.